# AVR ISP + Atmega16

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega

Есть микроконтроллер Atmega16L-8PU, который я пытаюсь прошить с помощью Arduino Mega 2560, используя скетч ArduinoISP и avrdude.

1. Создал тестовый проект в Atmel Studio, скомпилировал под Atmega16.
2. Прошил Arduino скетчем ArduinoISP
3. Подключил второй микроконтроллер, также установил конденсатор 10мкФ между Reset и GND Ардуино (без него ошибка "out of sync")
4. Запускаю avrdude:

`avrdude -v -p m16 -c avrisp -P COM3 -b 19200 -D -U flash:w:".\hex\test.hex":i`

```
avrdude: Version 5.4-arduino, compiled on Oct 11 2007 at 19:12:32
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\Public\avr\avrdude.conf"

         Using Port            : COM3
         Using Programmer      : avrisp
         Overriding Baud Rate  : 19200
         AVR Part              : ATMEGA16
         Chip Erase delay      : 9000 us
         PAGEL                 : PD7
         BS2                   : PA0
         RESET disposition     : dedicated
         RETRY pulse           : SCK
         serial program mode   : yes
         parallel program mode : yes
         Timeout               : 200
         StabDelay             : 100
         CmdexeDelay           : 25
         SyncLoops             : 32
         ByteDelay             : 0
         PollIndex             : 3
         PollValue             : 0x53
         Memory Detail         :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom         4    10   128    0 no        512    4      0  9000  9000 0xff 0xff
           flash         33     6   128    0 yes     16384  128    128  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          4    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel AVR ISP
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Видно, что сигнатура устройства неверная (`0x000000`). (**UPD:** Если запустить avrdude без подключенного целевого МК, то происходит абсолютно такой же вывод в консоль, т.е. проблема в том, что целевой МК не обнаруживается в принципе).

В скетче ArduinoISP сделал `#define SPI_CLOCK (128000/6)`.

Если в avrdude установить флаг -F, то запись как будто бы идет, но проверка в итоге не проходит:

```
avrdude: Version 5.4-arduino, compiled on Oct 11 2007 at 19:12:32
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\Public\avr\avrdude.conf"

         Using Port            : COM3
         Using Programmer      : avrisp
         Overriding Baud Rate  : 19200
         AVR Part              : ATMEGA16
         Chip Erase delay      : 9000 us
         PAGEL                 : PD7
         BS2                   : PA0
         RESET disposition     : dedicated
         RETRY pulse           : SCK
         serial program mode   : yes
         parallel program mode : yes
         Timeout               : 200
         StabDelay             : 100
         CmdexeDelay           : 25
         SyncLoops             : 32
         ByteDelay             : 0
         PollIndex             : 3
         PollValue             : 0x53
         Memory Detail         :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom         4    10   128    0 no        512    4      0  9000  9000 0xff 0xff
           flash         33     6   128    0 yes     16384  128    128  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          4    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel AVR ISP
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
avrdude: Expected signature for ATMEGA16 is 1E 94 03
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as 0
avrdude: reading input file ".\hex\test.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (150 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.48s

avrdude: 150 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against .\hex\test.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file .\hex\test.hex:
avrdude: input file .\hex\test.hex contains 150 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.34s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0x0c != 0x00
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as 0
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

P.S. Atmega16 новая.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в качестве подключения: изначально собирал на макетной плате. В итоге спаял надстройку с нормальными соединениями и все заработало.

UPD: Спустя несколько месяцев столкнулся опять с такой же проблемой с такими же симптомами. На этот раз ошибка была в том, что `RESET` брался с 10-го пина (как по-умолчанию в скетче Arduino ISP), а в схеме у меня был подключен другой пин.